# javascript jquery expand collapse search results

Tags: javascript, php

I have this bit of code below which expands and collapses the results from a search. The search displays the search results on the same page so the whole page isn't reloaded. It works the first time - i.e the first search, however for future searches the expand collapse feature stops working. I think its because the page isn't reloaded but Im not sure how to fix it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2   /jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
$('.section').hide();
 $('h2').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("open");
    $(this).next().toggle();
}); //end toggle

}); //end ready

</script>

<?php include('db.php');
$descr = $_POST['search'];
 echo '<ul id="user_list">';
 $user_query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tblVulns WHERE Name LIKE '%".$descr."%'");
 while($user = $db->fetch_assoc($user_query))
 {
      echo ' <h2 style="cursor:pointer">'.stripslashes($user['Name']).'</h2>
    <div class="section" style="display:none">  <h3>'.stripslashes($user['Risk']).'</h3><p>
    <h4>'.stripslashes($user['Summary']).'<p>'
    .stripslashes($user['Description']).'<p>'
    .stripslashes($user['cveCode']).'<p></div>';
 }
?>
```

The code at the bottom is the php receiving the search results. The code at the top is the js that is dealing with expand and collapse

Any help in how to get this work for all searches after the page has loaded would be great. Thanks

Comment: How you supposed to receive the future search results without reloading the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding your event listener to the click event of any `h2` elements that are present on page load. It sounds like you are then loading in new content and expecting the same code to work for them.

Instead, you will need to do this:

```
$("body").on("click","h2",function(){
     $(this).toggleClass("open");
     $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

Which will work on any `h2` that is on the page. If you want only `h2`s in a certain container to have the effect then replace `body` for a reference to that element

EDIT:

I see now that you are using quite an old version of jQuery that doesn't support the `on()` function. I would suggest upgrading if you can, or use Abhishek Saha's answer if you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the reason, it doesnt work after the first search is because the new element which gets loaded, is not bind with the click action.

Try this:

replace

```
$('h2').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("open");
    $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

with

```
$('h2').live('click',function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("open");
    $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

Comment: From the jQuery docs: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. **Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()**.

Comment: Apologies, I see that `delegate()` wasn't actually present in jQuery 1.3.2.

Comment: .on() would be a better option to use...Sorry i was aware about the live() method being deprecated but it just slipped my mind. Didn't code for a month...